# Error when trying to get time from date which has timezone info also

Tags: php, datetime

My sample date is like this, which includes timezone format also at the end.

> 2018-04-13T15:36:00-05:00

I tried below code

```
date("H:i:s", "2018-04-13T15:36:00-05:00");
```

Timezone part is :   `-05:00`

I got an error: A non well formed numeric value encountered. Am I missing anything?

**Update 1**

```
$time = strtotime("2018-04-13T15:36:00-05:00");
echo date("H:i", $time));
```

I tried above code but the current output is

> 20:36

and expected output is 15:36

Comment: maybe `strtotime` or with `DateTime`? the sec. parameter from `date` must be a timestamp

Comment: Second argument of `date` is __int__. Do you see __int__ in your code?

Comment: Now work with the timezone.

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set` is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class which has built in support for TimeZones and translations between them.

```
$dt = new DateTime('2018-04-13T15:36:00-05:00');

echo $dt->format('H:i');
```